# how to get Labelencoder.Classes_ when using label encoder in defaultdict?

Tags: python, encoding, defaultdict

I have used the following method to Label Encode my train data.

this method works fine, but in the testing set i need to take care of new levels which are not fitted in the training set. To do this i need the LabelEncoder.Classes_

```
from collections import defaultdict
label_dict = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
fit = df.apply(lambda x: label_dict[x.name].fit(x))
```

but how to get the Classes information when using LabelEncoder in defaultdict?

Answer (score 0):

You can try
`label_dict['dataframe header'].classes_`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? It's not clear what you mean simply from this

Comment: all the `label.enconder()` was inserted into label_dict dictionary. My method is to show classes for one of the key name